# MATLAB: why I am not getting any output?

Tags: matlab, if-statement, for-loop, output

Why my code does not compute the variable `cos_theta`, and then `theta`?

Code:

```
alpha = alpha_min:alpha_step:alpha_max;
cos_theta_0 = -1./(2.*alpha)+sqrt(1.+1./(4.*alpha.^2));
theta_0 = acos(cos_theta_0);
hmax = (sqrt(1+4.*alpha.^2)-1)./(2.*log(2));

for h = 1:(K-2);
    if h<= hmax;
    cos_theta(h,:) = cos_theta_0- h.*log(2)./alpha;
    theta(h,:) = acos(cos_theta(h,:));
    else break;
    end 
end
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: Also: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @dasdingonesin sorry, I am not confident with Matlab, and I am trying to improve it as quickly as I can.

Comment: Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and include a proper description of your problem. "does not compute" does not describe the problem sufficiently.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you are trying to do here:

```
h <= hmax
```

You are comparing a constant 'h' with a vector 'hmax'.

Comment: thank you, but I transcript my code in a wrong way. Parentheses are ok, but it still doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: To know which loop is being entered, you need to tell us the values of alpha and K that you are using.

Comment: `K=8`, `alpha_step = 0.5;
alpha_min = 1;
alpha_max = 10.;`, and in a subsequent trial I set `h` with the same schema.

Comment: thanks, I noticed that I am moving in the right direction although I still don't have any answer from my code.